# Don't allow access to wp-admin but allow admin-ajax requests to be fulfilled on frontend?

Tags: multisite, ajax, wp-admin

I have a site that requires users to have an acccount to use it. I don't want certain user roles to have access to wp-admin. All account changes should happen on the frontend account management templates. If a user tries to access wp-admin I want to redirect them back to the site homepage.

```
function redirect_user(){
    //...some code...

    //Have tried:
    //if(empty(DOING_AJAX) && $users_role =='somerandomrole') //this works on frontend but allows access to wp-admin
    //if(is_admin() && $users_role =='somerandomrole') //stops access to wp-admin but then frontend stops working
    if((is_admin() || !empty(DOING_AJAX)) && $users_role =='somerandomrole')
    {
         wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
         exit;
    }
 }
 add_action('admin_init', 'redirect_user');
```

The problem I have is there are dynamic components to our site such as a search tool that makes requests through admin-ajax.php but due to the logic redirects the request (i.e no search results). Is there a way to make this work?

**Edit:**
Ok so one solution that does seem to work although it doesn't feel right is:

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' && $users_role =='somerandomrole'){
//...code...
}
```

Is there a bad side effect to doing it this way?

Comment: What happens with `if(is_admin() && empty(DOING_AJAX) && $users_role =='somerandomrole')`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check `is_admin` because the function is hooked to `admin_init`, so `is_admin()` is always `true` in the callback; that makes  that `( is_admin() || !empty(DOING_AJAX) )` always verify as `true`. You only need to check if the constant `DOING_AJAX` is not defined or if it is defined and it is `false` (both cases are not an AJAX request), combined with the user role. For example, to allow AJAX and access only to `administrator` role:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_user' );

function redirect_user() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( ( !defined('DOING_AJAX') || ! DOING_AJAX ) && ( empty( $user ) || !in_array( "administrator", (array) $user->roles ) ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }

}
```

Also, you can consider to check capabilities instead of roles. For example:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_user' );

function redirect_user() {

    if( ( !defined('DOING_AJAX') || ! DOING_AJAX ) && ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }

}
```